# autofill data from a sheet to a sheet named after a current month

Tags: vba, excel

I want to track the daily, monthly records of my shop.

My first sheet is where I record all the earnings for the day. I made an update button that transfers all of the data collected at the end of the day to the next worksheets, which are named after the months.

I successfully made it on the month of July because I just typed in "July" to select the worksheet where the data will be transferred.

But what I want to get is automatically selecting the worksheet based on the current month, where the next worksheets are named after.

I tried

```vb
worksheets(format(now,"mmm")).select
```

but I'm getting an error stating that I am out of range

here's my whole code:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo, "Title") = vbYes Then

    Dim CtrlCDate As String, CtrlCPSQty As Integer, CtrlCPSAmt As Integer, CtrlCPLQty As Integer, CtrlCPLAmt As Integer, CtrlCPQty As Integer, CtrlCPamt As Integer, CtrlCSQty As Integer, CtrlCSAmt As Integer, TC As Integer, TL As Integer, TS As Integer
        Worksheets("CTRLC Ops").Select
        CtrlCDate = Range("N3")
        CtrlCPSQty = Range("N6")
        CtrlCPSAmt = Range("O6")
        CtrlCPLQty = Range("N7")
        CtrlCPLAmt = Range("O7")
        CtrlCPQty = Range("N8")
        CtrlCPamt = Range("O8")
        CtrlCSQty = Range("N9")
        CtrlCSAmt = Range("O9")
        TC = Range("O10")
        TL = Range("O11")
        TS = Range("N13")
        Worksheets("July").Select
        Worksheets("July").Range("A3").Select
        If Worksheets("July").Range("A3").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
        Worksheets("July").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Select
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CtrlCDate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CtrlCPSQty
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CtrlCPSAmt
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CtrlCPLQty
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CtrlCPLAmt
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CtrlCPQty
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CtrlCPamt
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CtrlCSQty
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CtrlCSAmt
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = TC
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = TL
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = TS
        Worksheets("CTRLC Ops").Select
        Worksheets("CTRLC Ops").Range("D1").Select
 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Worksheets(Format(now,"mmm")).Select will select a worksheet called "Jul". Is that the name of the sheet, or is it July?

"mmm" will return the first three letters of the month, "mmmm" will return the full month name.

So if you want to select worksheet "July", then use Worksheets(Format(now,"mmmm")).Select